# Finding Actionscript within an FLA file

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am dealing with a Flash file which has been created by a third party. It has a lot of folders and files in the library and I can't seem to find any ActionScript anywhere.

Is there a simple way of finding the location of ActionScript when the author has been naughty and not labelled it or put it in a sensible place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to @grapefrukt's answer: Make sure you toggle the ShowActionscript button
in the Movie Explorer. That would be the third icon, the one with the blue arrow.

[image: Movie Explorer]

You can use the **Find** field to look search for common actions like: stop(), .visible, etc.

Alternatively you can use the **Find And Replace Panel (Ctrl+F / CMD + F)** and search for **Text** (common actions) and tick **ActionScript** only.

[image: Find And Replace]

*Note:* The Find And Replace Panel is a separate panel, do not confuse it with the Find And Replace functionality in the Actions Panel.

Also, I think you could find actions using the Script Navigator, inside the Actions Panel's Toolbox:

[image: Action's Panel]

HTH

Comment: When doing this, make sure to drag everything you want to search within onto the stage.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the Movie Explorer, `Window -> Movie Explorer`, or `ALT + F3` in Windows. This lets you explore all assets that are added to the stage in a tree like fashion. It wont show items that are dynamically added from the library, but it might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I would export to swf then open it with a reverse engineer tool (like Sothink SWF Decompiler) and look through all the scripts/actions. The action name will tell you where to find it if you still need that (you'll see the decompiled code).