# Flash Professional how to find a class

Tags: flash, class, actionscript

I there:

I have some experience working with Flex but im feel clueless working with flash pro.

My problem is that i found a flash project that i want to edit (.fla), this project contain an actionscript class in some part that i am unable to find.

How to find a class in Flash Professional?.

I know that the class exist in the project because i generate a swf file and decompile it and it show the class.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Probably start with the Document Class then move to other classes that might be used.

If you go to **File > Publish Settings** in the **Flash** tab click the **Settings** button next to the script (ActionScript 3.0) settings.

[image: flash publish settings]

Once you get to the ActionScript 3.0 settings, you can see the path to the used classes.

[image: actionscript 3.0 settings]

This image displays the Library Path, you need the **Source Path** tab.

If your fla has code in the timeline also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092377/finding-actionscript-within-an-fla-file/3092837#3092837).

HTH

Comment: i check it but it is a isolated fla file, so it does not use any external file (excluding the default libraries).

Comment: @magallanes then the only other option is code in the timeline. As I mentioned above, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092377/finding-actionscript-within-an-fla-file/3092837#3092837 for tips to find code in the timeline

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you can put ActionScript code: in a separate .as file that gets referred to by the .fla, and in the Actions window attached to specific frames. Look at the timeline; if you see any @ symbols that means there is code attached to that frame. Go to that frame and open the Actions window.

This also applies to the timelines of the various MovieClips. It is really bad practice to deeply embed code like that but people still do it.

Comment: i tried both method. First, there are not a separated actionscript and second, exist some code attached to some frames (even when it does not show the @) but im still unable to find the code.  Also i tried Movie explorer and Find function.  Apparently the code is attached to some object attached to the code (a swf file)..

Comment: @magallanes "Apparently the code is attached to some object attached to the code" O_o