# Search/Find All ActionScript Code Flash CS 5.5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've received a large number of flash files which I need to modify. There is no documentation anywhere, and the code appears to be all over the place. There are a ton of errors occurring (which give me some slightly useful information, like what method caused the error), but I'm having a terrible time trying to actually *locate* the offending code.

Is there some way to search *all* actionscript in a given flash file for a certain string (i.e. a method name)?

Or do I really have to look through every layer of every movieclip trying to find the code by hand?

Comment: Generally it's a pain, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092377/finding-actionscript-within-an-fla-file

Comment: In the Publish Settings switch "Permit Debugging" option on and it will give you much more precise location of the erroring code.